# IOS get user location indoor using ibeacons and custome image of floor map

Tags: ios, swift4, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I've deployed some iBeacon  devices in several rooms of a building's floor for testing, and I'd like to find the user's current indoor location on a custom image of the floor map .
in fact ,i didn't work with estimote beacons cause that i haven't access to the cloud  , i using onether marque of beacons.

I've been already reading about monitoring iBeacon regions, but I do not know how to deal with the following tasks:

To create an image of the floor I could use in the app
To map user's locations on the floor image: how could I draw positions on my custom floor image
I'd appreciate some guidence or a starting point, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source solution for indoor positioning, but I'm not sure if it allows you to draw the position on a map / image: https://github.com/schollz/find

There's a few commercial solutions like https://indoo.rs/ that support this for sure. (I know because I work for that company)